# What is the difference between send_data and send_file in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sendfile

Which one is best for streaming and file downloads?

Please provide examples.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

```
send_data(_data_, options = {})
send_file(_path_, options = {})
```

Main difference here is that you pass DATA (binary code or whatever) with **send_data** or file PATH with **send_file**.

So you can generate some data and send it as an inline text or as an attachment without generating file on your server via **send_data**. Or you can send ready file with **send_file**

```
data = "Hello World!"
send_data( data, :filename => "my_file.txt" )
```

Or

```
data = "Hello World!"
file = "my_file.txt"
File.open(file, "w"){ |f| f << data }
send_file( file )
```

For perfomance it is better to generate file once and then send it as many times as you want. So `send_file` will fit better.

For streaming, as far as I understand, both of this methods use the same bunch of options and settings, so you can use X-Send or whatever.

**UPD**

send_data and save file:

```
data = "Hello World!"
file = "my_file.txt"
File.open(file, "w"){ |f| f << data }
send_data( data )
```

Comment: thanks @fl00r. Is there way to save the data as file and then send, using the send_data function?. Because, i needed a copy of the file in my server. How can i achieve that?.

Comment: There's an error in your code: it should be `{ |f|  f << data }`.

Comment: Hi, I'm wondering if this answer is still relevant? I'm using Rails 3.2.16 now and using `send_file` I had to use the file itself, not the path in order to get it to work. Just wanted to update in case others run across this?

Answer (score 24):

**send_file may be faster than send_data**

As [fl00r mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5536157/895245), `send_file` takes a path, and `send_data` the data.

Therefore `send_file` is a subset of `send_data`, as you need a file on the filesystem: you could of course just read the file and use `send_data` on it. But `send_file` can be faster, so it is a performance / generality trade-off.

`send_file` can be faster because it can send the [`X-Sendfile`](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) header on Apache ([`X-Accel-Redirect`](http://wiki.nginx.org/X-accel) on Nginx) instead of the file content, since it knows the path.

This header is consumed by the reverse proxy (Apache or Nginx) which normally runs in front of Rails in a production setup.

If `X-Sendfile` is present on the response, the reverse proxy ignores most of the current response, and builds a new one that returns the file at the given path.

```
Client <---> Internet <---> Reverse proxy <---> Rails
```

This is much more efficient since the reverse proxy is highly specialized at serving static files, and can do it much faster than Rails (which does not send the file data if `X-Sendfile` will be sent).

The typical use case of `send_file` is when you want to control the access permission of static files: you cannot put them under `/public` or else they would get served before Rails has a chance to decide. This is discussed at: [Protecting the content of public/ in a Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143300/protecting-the-content-of-public-in-a-rails-app)

In order to use the `X-Sendfile` headers, you have to add:

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx
```

to `config/initializers/production.rb` (or `config/environment/production.rb` in Rails 5.x), **not** `application.rb`, since in development you don't have a proxy server and you want `send_file` to actually send the data.

`X-Sendfile` is discussed on the [Asset Pipeline Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#x-sendfile-headers).