# Using send_file to download a zip file to browser without rails server being involved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

I am using the following snippet to allow a user to download a zip file. The path here is a link on the S3 bucket. I want to confirm if the file would be directly downloaded from S3 to the browser or would it first be downloaded to the rails server & then streamed from there?

If the latter, what is the best way to avoid that?

```
path = "#{file.download_attachment.path}"  
send_file path, :type => 'application/zip',
                :disposition => 'attachment',
                :filename => "#{file.name}.zip"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer on this question: [Difference between rails send_data and send_file, with example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535981/difference-between-rails-send-data-and-send-file-with-example) will explain you the difference between send_file and send_data.

If you like to stream something, use send_data. If you like to send an already existing file, use send_file, so your code seems to work the way you like ;)