# Trying to download files from a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having trouble downloading files from rails applications. If someone can give me some insight on what I am missing and doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it. Also, I have been reading up on `send_data` and `send_file`. I do not understand what it means when asking to send DATA for `send_data`, while PATH for `send_file`. What's the difference? Thanks again!

**routes.rb**

```
    resources :companies do
     member do
       get 'send_document'
     end
    end
```

view code (in static_pages_controller, not companies_controller)

```
     <ul>
    <% @companies.each do |company| %>
        <li>
            <%= company.compName %>
            <%= company.formType %>
            <%= company.fileLocation %>
            <%= link_to "View Document", controller: :companies,             send_document_path(company), , method: :get %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

**companies_controller.rb**

```
def send_document
 @company = Company.find(params[:id])
 send_file "#{@company.fileLocation}"
end
```

Error: I am receiving an error on the link_to line. I am having trouble trying to download a file with specific companies in my database. Any help is appreciated. Thanks! Also, in the companies_controller, the code Company.find(params[:id]) is saying it is without a company id.

UPDATE: I changed the code to be

```
    <%= link_to "View Document", send_document_path(company), {controller: :companies}, method: :get %>
```

and am now receiving this error:

```
app/views/layouts/_search_bar.html.erb where line #6 raised:

undefined method `send_document_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000005446998>:0x00000004147360>

Extracted source (around line #6):

3
4
5
6<%= link_to "View Document", send_document_path(company), {controller: :companies},   method: :get %>
7
8
9
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: can you post the error??

Comment: Hi Gagan! Thanks for replying. I have updated my post with the new error I have found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your routes file, you've got your path specified incorrectly in your link, and you don't need to specify the controller.

```
<%= link_to "View Document", send_document_path(company), {controller: :companies}, method: :get %>
```

should be

```
<%= link_to "View Document", send_document_company_path(company), method: :get %>
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. Do you know where I can find documentation on to know what path to write. How did you know it was send_document_company_path and not just send_document_path? Thanks again!

Comment: run 'rake routes' in a console to see all of your routes.  The paths for each route will appear in the first (left) column. I realized the path was incorrect after comparing your routes file setup to one of mine that also attaches an action to a member, and noticed my route had the model name attached to that action's path, unlike yours.

Comment: As far as the second part of your question, it's similar to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535981/difference-between-rails-send-data-and-send-file-with-example).  BTW, @DariusTran if this proves to be the solution to your problem, it'd be nice of you to mark it as 'answered.'  :)

Comment: Thank you! I thought I did. Check click the checkmark right?

Comment: Yes.  You got it.  Glad to hear it worked, too!  And you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**send_data(data, options = {})**

Sends the given binary data to the browser. This method is similar to render plain: data, but also allows you to specify whether the browser should display the response as a file attachment (i.e. in a download dialog) or as inline data. You may also set the content type, the apparent file name, and other things.

---

**send_file(path, options = {})**

Sends the file. This uses a server-appropriate method (such as X-Sendfile) via the Rack::Sendfile middleware. The header to use is set via config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header. Your server can also configure this for you by setting the X-Sendfile-Type header.

**[More Info](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data)**

**EDIT :**

I found syntax error in your code:

```
<%= link_to "View Document", controller: :companies,             send_document_path(company), , method: :get %>
```

in above line after `send_document_path(company)` there are two times comma(`,`) may there is an error..

**Update:**

```
<%= link_to "View Document", :url => { :controller => "companies", :action => "send_document(company)" } ,:method => :get %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to "View Document", controller: :companies, send_document_path(company), , method: :get %>
```

it should be not `,,` just a single `,`

```
 <%= link_to "View Document", controller: :companies, send_document_path(company),  method: :get %>
```

Comment: Sorry, that was just a mistype on my part when putting the code onto stackoverflow. It is saying that the ( ) is causing a syntax error. Thanks though!

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => ...s, send_document_path(company), method: :get );@output_buffe... ... ^

Comment: yes please use my link_to post  `<%= link_to "View Document", controller: :companies, send_document_path(company),  method: :get %>` this one

Comment: I used that code and received the same exact error.

Comment: Hi Rajarshi. I've fixed the error by adding { } around the controller. I am receiving a new error and was hoping you would be able to help. Thanks for the previous advice!