# How to download file with changed filename?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, cloudinary

Let's consider such case:

- I have an image which contains, for example, a guitar
- Its name is guitar.png
- After uploaded it changes name to random string like *kouyyvrmbubwkrh7ayvk.png*
- Now i want to have a link to this file, but clicking it should download the file with changed name, eg. "my-custom-attachment.png", or something

Now I'm using simple `<a>...</a>` with angular attribute:

```html
<a ng-href="{{ vm.resource.attachment_url }}"> Download attachment </a>
```

Where `vm.resource.attachment_url` is obviously fetched object with internal API

I wasn't able to find such implementation in Cloudinary API. Also, I hope I'm clear enough.

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535981/difference-between-rails-send-data-and-send-file-with-example. You can use `send_file` to rename the file accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudinary supports delivering images as attachments forcing it to download and store with its original filename.
This is done by simply adding the `fl_attachment` to the URL, or setting the `flags` parameter to **attachment** when using the helper methods, e.g.:
`cloudinary.url('kouyyvrmbubwkrh7ayvk.png', {flags: 'attachment'});`

In your specific case this will result with the image being saved as **guitar.png**.

More information: http://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202521252-How-can-I-deliver-an-image-as-an-attachment-

Answer (score 0):

Use the `download` [attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) of the anchor, which specifies what name will receive the downloaded file:

```
<a ng-href="{{ vm.resource.attachment_url }}" download="my-custom-attachment.png"> Download attachment </a>
```

See [the demo](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download2) how the attribute works.

Another option is to download the file content into a Blob object, and then throw the blob content with a modified filename. Check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/koldev/cw7w5/).

Comment: Looks nice but it works only for local files. I need to fetch files from cloudinary and change name, in which case the `download` attribute doesn't work

Comment: @blisher What do you mean for local files? It does download the remote file and change the name according to `download` attribute value.

Comment: If you change `href` attribute to `http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/` in the demo it doesn't work anymore